# How to extract id names from search result urls using rvest? (CSS selector isn't working)

Tags: css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm attempting to extract a list of product item names from a search result page ([link here](https://www.fishersci.com/us/en/catalog/search/products?keyword=sodium+hydroxide&nav=)).

```
library(rvest)
results <- read_html('https://www.fishersci.com/us/en/catalog/search/products?keyword=sodium+hydroxide&nav=')
results %>%
  html_nodes(".result_title a") %>%
  html_text()
```

which returns

```
character(0)
```

I've also attempted to make use of:

```
html_attr('href')
```

with no luck.  Can I even use css to pull the titles of these links?  I'm trying to make a list of the 30 product results (e.g. "Sodium Hydroxide (Pellets/Certified ACS), Fisher Chemical").  Is the id for these links using javascript?

Thanks for any help, this is my first scraping project and my knowledge of web design is much simpler than this particular page.

Answer (score 1):

The result is indeed generated with javascript. `rvest` doesn't handle javascript at the moment, but other alternatives exists.

For example, you can use [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) to get to what you want :

```
library(RSelenium) # Wrapper around Selenium
library(wdman)     # helper to download and configure phantomjs
library(rvest)

phantomjs <- phantomjs(port = 4444L)
remote_driver <- remote_driver(browserName = "phantomjs", port = 4444L)
remote_driver <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", port = 4444L)
remote_driver$open(silent = TRUE)
remote_driver$navigate("https://www.fishersci.com/us/en/catalog/search/products?keyword=sodium+hydroxide&nav=")
remote_driver$getPageSource()[[1]]

page_source %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(css = '.result_title') %>% 
  html_text()
```